# Can I bind the Height of a XAML Grid back to my C# back end code?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have some XAML code that looks like this. It names four grids and then in the back end my C# does something based on the values. As I can not have duplicate names I created four names.

But I would like to simplify the back-end code so is it possible that I could bind back the value of the height from my XAML > ViewModel and then check that value in my C#

```
<Grid IsVisible="{Binding AVisible}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
   <Grid x:Name="aWords" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
      <Frame VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
         <Frame.Content>
            <Grid x:Name="aArea" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
               <Label Text="{Binding Detail}"
            </Grid>
         </Frame.Content>
      </Frame>
   </Grid>
</Grid>
<Grid IsVisible="{Binding BVisible}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
   <Grid x:Name="bWords" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
      <Frame VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
         <Frame.Content>
            <Grid x:Name="bArea" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
               <Label Text="{Binding Detail}"
            </Grid>
         </Frame.Content>
      </Frame>
   </Grid>
</Grid>
```

and in C#

```
var a = aWords.Height;
var b = aArea.Height;
if (b > a) doSomething();

var c = aWords.Height;
var d = aArea.Height;
if (d > c) doSomething();
```

What I would like to do is like this:

```
if (vm.AreaHeight > vm.WordsHeight) doSomething();
```

Comment: If define `AreaHeight` and `WordsHeight` in model,and need to get height from XAML,then it can be possible.

Answer (score 0):

The way you can pass those values to your ViewModel is by using the **binding context** of your page for interacting with the ViewModel methods and properties.

First, create a couple of properties in your ViewModel to hold the Height of your objects: i.e.:

```cs
public int AreaHeight { get; set; }
public int WordsHeight { get; set; }
```

Then, on your page override the event: **OnAppearing()** in order to get the Height from your grids using the **x:Name** attribute, then you will call from your ViewModel the method: doSomething() passing the obtained values as parameters. i.e.:

```cs
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        // Get your height from your grids here ...
        // int gridAHeight = aWords.Height;
        // int gridBHeight = aArea.Height;
        (BindingContext as YourViewModel).doSomething(gridAHeight, gridBHeight);
    }
```

Finally, in your ViewModel, implement the method doSomething() and catch the parameters obtained from the view page by assigning them to your previously created properties. i.e:

```cs
public void DoSomething(int gridAHeight, int gridBHeight)
{
    AreaHeight = gridAHeight;
    WordsHeight = gridBHeight;
    if (AreaHeight < WordsHeight)
    {
       // place your logic here...
    }
}
```

That is all you need. It is just **basic MVVM pattern**.

Comment: While calling to the **ViewModel** might be the MVVM pattern, the `ViewModel` shouldn't know anything about a specific view. Passing heights dependent on a single page, **violates** that.

Answer (score 0):

Passing heights or binding heights to a `ViewModel` violates MVVM pattern. ViewModels shouldn't know anything about a specific view.

I would suggest refactoring your view and finding a different layout depending on the specifics needed for the page. A possible solution would be to use a `ListView` with labels and restricting the content in the `ObservableCollection` so you don't have duplicates.

If you have to have it set up that way, I would suggest using `MaxLines` and/or `LineBreakMode` to restrict the height of your Labels.

**Issues with doing logic based on height:**

1. `FontSize` could be different based on AccessibilitySettings specified in the users phone
2. Rotating the screen will change how much of the label is wrapped due to the label **expanding**. This would force you to do a recalculation again.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can't. There isn't the height in XAML, but rather `HeightRequest`. The layout is a complex thing and the height may not end up being what is your `HeightRequest`, it is just a suggested value. So you can only change that suggested value from the view model that is not the problem, but that is not what you asked for.